# NATS maximum cluster size

Tags: nats.io

What is a realistic max number of servers for a NATS cluster for a *very specific scenario* described below?

*My scenario is:* many replicas of my service (think k8s PODs) will each have an instance of `nats-server` running, replicas will rarely be added and removed (e.g. once-per-minute max), and PUBs will be rare as well (e.g. once-per-second max).

Would 100 servers work well? Would 1000?

Answer (score 3):

In general clusters can be on the smaller side, so not sure you will need that many at all.

When scaling clusters we look at the following.

1. Network Bandwidth
2. CPU - >3Ghz and 4+ cores works well. If very large N connections to a server then more cores can help.
3. Memory, more comes into play with JetStream or large number of connections. Non JS servers that are mostly idle have been known to sit at ~30MB, but JetStream can require more, we usually recommend 8GB there.
4. Thundering herd. If you have lots of connections and they are all TLS with large RSA keys this could be an issue along with #2. Larger clusters help here and we do have client jitter on reconnect. Also if you can, ECC keys for TLS helps quite a bit here.

Hope that helps a bit.